# Hide Side view of PDF in in iframe

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, embed

I am trying to embed a PDF and I would like the side view to be hidden by default. I can only seem to achieve that by hiding the toolbar. I want the toolbar to be visible, but not the side menu by default. Is there anyway I can achieve this?
Code:
         `<iframe src="../json/invoicePdf.html?order=`vlcLocOrder`#toolbar=0&navpanes=0" height="550px" width="91%" > </iframe>`

Current:
[image]

What I want to be by default:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

add view="fit",
hope this solve your problem